# Joblist in IBM i /AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am tryin to filter a job form job list in IBM i/as400 based on the following parameters
JOBNAME,USERNAME, STATUS and Entered date.
The reason behind is to find the job id of the latest instance of a particular job for subsequent processing.

So far I have tried WRKJOB, WRKACTJOB, WRKUSRJOB, DSPJOB commands. But with these comamands I am not able to fetch the JOBID by passsing the above parameters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention if the job is currently active or already ended...

I'd suggest taking a look at the available [Work Management SQL Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-work-management)

It's likely that the [ACTIVE_JOB_INFO User Defined Table Function (UDTF)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-active-job-info-table-function)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(QSYS2.ACTIVE_JOB_INFO(
            JOB_NAME_FILTER => 'MYJOB',
            SUBSYSTEM_LIST_FILTER => 'QBATCH')) X;
```

Or [ENDED_JOB_INFO UDTF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-ended-job-info-table-function) will have the information you want.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (SYSTOOLS.ENDED_JOB_INFO() )
  WHERE JOB_NAME = 'MYJOB';
```